# Wordpress PHP - Replace part of string in image URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin that force me to use a particular image, but I want to use a different one.

Would it be possible, through functions.php, to change part of the image URL?

So from:
http://www.wp-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/forced-img.png

to:
http://www.wp-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/new-image.png

Comment: almost certainly possible but impossible to answer categorically.

Comment: could you not, give the new image the same name and placement in the uploads - and then delete/rename the forced one? remember to clear caches afterwards